# Monkey patching built-in ruby classes in limited scopes

Tags: ruby, dsl, monkeypatching, instance-eval

I'm working on an internal Ruby DSL and to make it look as pretty as possible I need to monkey patch the Symbol class and add some operators. I want to be responsible in how I do this and would like to limit the scope and lifetime of the patches to a specific block of code. Is there a standard pattern for doing this? Here's some pseudo-code to show what I'm thinking:

```
class SomeContext
  def self.monkey_patch_region(&block)
    context = SomeContext.new
    context.monkey_patch_Symbol
    context.instance_eval(&block)
    context.unmonkey_patch_Symbol
  end

  # magical method
  def monkey_patch_Symbol
    #...
  end

  # another magical method
  def unmonkey_patch_Symbol
    #...
  end
```

end

Comment: I've made a simple (but useful enough for me) flavour of refinements. Maybe it can be useful for someone. http://rubychallenger.blogspot.com.br/2012/12/refinements-in-ruby-ingenuous.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe, that you're looking for ruby [refinements](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4085). The feature has landed in ruby trunk, but it might be reverted before 2.0

Answer (score 1):

I've heard about [mixology gem](https://github.com/dan-manges/mixology). It was designed to mixin and unmix modules. Maybe it can be useful to monkey and unmonkey patches.

**UPDATE:** mixology won't help you, as it (un)mixes modules to objects (as with `extend`), not to classes (as with `include`), and you want monkey/unmonkey core classes, not their objects individually. Anyway I intend to maintain this answer as possibly useful reference for someone else.